# Why is java showing me exception when i am taking input from the user?

Tags: java, exception, sum, java.util.scanner, control-flow

```
public static void inputThenPrintSumAndAverage (){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count =0;
        int sum =0 ;
        long average = 0;
        boolean isAnInt = scanner.hasNextInt();
        while (true) {
            count++;
            int number = scanner.nextInt();
            if (isAnInt) {
                sum+=number;
                average = Math.round((sum/count));
            } else {
                break;
            }
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("SUM = "+sum+ " AVG = "+average);
        scanner.close();
    }
```

When I am giving it a string it gives exception and doesn't even execute the "sum and avg" values. How can I change the code to make it work? If I have some wrong conceptual knowledge please help me understand the concept. Thank you.

Comment: You need to test for `.hasNextInt` ***within*** the while loop, not just before it. You need to test before getting *each* in put. You also should call `.nextLine()` *immediately* after getting the int.

Comment: But still its not working :(. Showing exception again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You do not need `Scanner#hasNextInt` for `Scanner(System.in)`. Also, you do not need the check, `if (isAnInt)`. Instead, you should put a `try-catch` block.
2. You should not close `Scanner(System.in)`; otherwise, there is no way to open it again without restarting the JVM.

Both the above thing are required when you use the `Scanner` for a `File`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        inputThenPrintSumAndAverage();
    }

    public static void inputThenPrintSumAndAverage() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        long average = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                int number = scanner.nextInt();
                sum += number;
                count++;
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
        average = Math.round((sum / count));
        System.out.println("SUM = " + sum + " AVG = " + average);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
2
3
5
8
abc
SUM = 18 AVG = 4
```

**Note:** you can get a better precision for average if you declare it as `double` and store the floating-point calculation into it without rounding e.g.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        inputThenPrintSumAndAverage();
    }

    public static void inputThenPrintSumAndAverage() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        double average = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                int number = scanner.nextInt();
                sum += number;
                count++;
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
        average = (double) sum / count;
        System.out.println("SUM = " + sum + " AVG = " + average);
    }
}
```

**A sample run after this change:**

```
2
3
5
8
abc
SUM = 18 AVG = 4.5
```

It will also be useful for you to understand [this concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/int-division-why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0).